# how to get the differences across several column groups

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<-structure(list(X1 = c(37L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, NA, 
11L, 12L), X2 = c(40L, NA, 35L, 35L, 35L, 34L, NA, 28L, 28L, 
NA, 25L, 24L), X3 = c(60L, 44L, 49L, 41L, NA, NA, NA, 25L, 26L, 
NA, NA, 22L), T1 = c(19L, 55L, 47L, 46L, 36L, 42L, 25L, NA, 33L, 
42L, 50L, 22L), T2 = c(75L, NA, 32L, 44L, 27L, 31L, 17L, NA, 
18L, 45L, 10L, 11L), T3 = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, NA, 
46L, 36L, 42L, NA), P1 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
NA, 1L, 12L), P2 = c(40L, 44L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 55L), P3 = c(1L, 44L, 49L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 25L, 26L, NA, 
NA, 66L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I have three groups and each group has 3 columns , they are called X, T and P.

I am trying to find out how many of rows in each group are overlapped with another group and how many rows in each group is different than another group. ( each row of each group must at lest have 2 values)

so I am looking for an output like this

```
X 10 rows overlapping with T and 2 different 
T has 10 overlapping with X and 2 different 
X has 10 overlapping with P and 1 different 
T has 10 overlapping with P and 3 different
```

it means I have 10 rows of X1,X2 and X3 which have at least 2 values and they have values in the group T (T1,T2,T3). There is one row that is completely empty or has only 1 value but they have values in T group. 
The same for other combination

Answer (score 0):

This question is still sort of ambiguous and narrow, but here is the general idea for tidying your data to the point where you can easily summarize over different groups and/or rows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  rowid_to_column %>%
  gather(select=-rowid) %>%
  separate(key, into=c('group', 'column'), sep=1) %>%
  group_by(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending along the lines of John Colby's answer, you can summarize how many rows are populated with 2 or more non-NA values in each letter's columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_summarized <- df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(colname, value, -rowid) %>%
  separate(colname, into = c("letter", "number"), sep = 1) %>%
  count(rowid, letter, wt = !is.na(value), name = "num_values") %>%
  mutate(populated = num_values >= 2)

> df_summarized
# A tibble: 36 x 4
   rowid letter num_values populated
   <int> <chr>       <int> <lgl>    
 1     1 P               3 TRUE     
 2     1 T               3 TRUE     
 3     1 X               3 TRUE     
 4     2 P               3 TRUE     
 5     2 T               2 TRUE     
 6     2 X               2 TRUE     
 7     3 P               3 TRUE     
 8     3 T               3 TRUE     
 9     3 X               3 TRUE     
10     4 P               3 TRUE 
# ... with 26 more rows
```

And then use that to compare between letters. For instance, here I see that 9 rows have the same populated / not-populated status among X and T columns. Three rows (7, 8, and 10) differ in their populated status between those two letters.

```
> df_summarized %>%
+   select(-num_values) %>%
+   spread(letter, populated)
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   rowid P     T     X    
   <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
 1     1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 2     2 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 3     3 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 4     4 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 5     5 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 6     6 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 7     7 FALSE TRUE  FALSE    # T but no X
 8     8 TRUE  FALSE TRUE     # X but no T
 9     9 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
10    10 FALSE TRUE  FALSE    # T but no X
11    11 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
12    12 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

We could query the data like this to get the overlaps and non-overlaps:

```
df_summarized %>% 
  select(-num_values) %>%
  spread(letter, populated) %>%
  summarize(PT = sum(P==T),
            PT_non = sum(P!=T),
            TX = sum(T==X),
            TX_non = sum(T!=X),
            XP = sum(X==P),
            XP_non = sum(X!=P))

# A tibble: 1 x 6
     PT PT_non    TX TX_non    XP XP_non
  <int>  <int> <int>  <int> <int>  <int>
1     9      3     9      3    12      0
```

Comment: is there any possibility to get the output like what I wrote? I basically want to use that for a Venn plot

Comment: Do you want a table with those values, or written out like your example?

Comment: it does not matter, whatever is easier for you

Comment: Added a way. Need to think more to make that calculation simpler.

Comment: it does not calculate it right, for example X and T have 10 rows that are having values more than 2 and is overlapping between the two. there are 2 rows in T that don't have all three values but I don't know how to calculate it 3